# C - Getting a string from user with user defined length

Tags: c

I know there are many questions with similar titles, I have not found the answer to my problem in any of them.

This is part of an assingment in a C programming workshop. I need to first get an integer from the user specifying the length of a string that I get subsequently.
The existing answers deal either with a situation where the maximal input size is known at compilation time or with cases where the input can be arbitrarily large (which make for very complicated solution)

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char *input =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n + 1));
    fgets(input, n, stdin);
    input[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s", input);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints nothing, how come?

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you. Can you think of an easy fix?

Comment: Try  `fgets(input, n, stdin); printf("<%s>\n", input); fgets(input, n, stdin); printf("<%s>\n", input);` to see the effect well commented by [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244016/c-getting-a-string-from-user-with-user-defined-length#comment93373436_53244016). Easy crappy fix: use `scanf("%d%*c", &n);`  Best fix is follow [@Broman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244016/c-getting-a-string-from-user-with-user-defined-length#comment93373478_53244016).

Comment: The easy fix is to not use scanf